# Material UI TreeView: Display multiple columns data from node in treeview

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, treeview

```
const treeItems = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'English',
        country: 'US',
        children: [
            {
                id: 4,
                name: 'Spring',
                country: 'Uk',
                children: []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 14,
        name: 'Italian',
        country: 'AUS',
        children: [
            {
                id: 24,
                name: 'Level A',
                country: 'IND',
                children: []
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I have data in tree format it can be hierarchical or flat so I have used tree view. But I also want to display all columns inside the node which is id, name & country in table view inside tree view.

**I am using Treeview from material UI**
I checked the documentation as well. I didn't find any solution yet.

**Below is the format I want to display**

```
ID                Name            Country
------------------------------------------
1                 English         US
    4                SPring         Uk
14                Italian         Aus
   24                Level A        IND
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is a little bit more tricky than [MUI TreeView example](https://material-ui.com/components/tree-view/). While example accepts data as JSON, in your case you have an array of JSON.

Supposing that you want to show `name` attribute in treeview label, you could write something like this:

```
<TreeView
  className={classes.root}
  defaultCollapseIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
  defaultExpanded={["root"]}
  defaultExpandIcon={<ChevronRightIcon />}
>
  {renderTree(data)} //<-- this is the function that recursively inspects your array
</TreeView>
```

Then the `renderTree` function:

```
const renderTree = (nodes) => {
return nodes.map((el) => { //<-- mapping on array
  return (
    <TreeItem key={el.id} nodeId={el.id.toString()} label={el.id + " " + el.name + " " + el.country}>
      {Array.isArray(el.children) && el.children.length > 0
        ? renderTree(el.children) //<-- recursion in case children has values
        : null}
    </TreeItem>
  );
});
};
```

The result is:

[image]

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-vc1fn?file=/demo.js) a working example.

Comment: Thanks For your answer.
I want to show the **ALL** data in table format with the header name.
eg:

id          name                country
1           English              US
   4           Spring              Uk
.......

Comment: @Abhinandanprasad I updated my answer. Is what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks. Will I able to display header Names also? and is it possible to have a filter and sorting based on columns?

Comment: also, how can I make sure the same column data should not appear beyond column length.

Comment: @Abhinandanprasad If you want functionality like filter on column or header maybe you could try with [MUI Table](https://material-ui.com/components/tables/). Take a look at collapsible table.